# Remove a suffix if present on a string column of a DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I'm using Spark 2.2. and I'd like to know what is the best option in term of performance to remove a suffix on a column of a `DataFrame`

Using an udf

```
val removeSuffix = udf { (id: String) =>
    if (id != null && id.endsWith("XXX")) {
      id.dropRight(3)
    } else {
      id
    }
  }
df.withColumn("c", udf("col"))
```

Or using the `regexp` built-in function

```
df.withColumn("c", regexp_replace($"col", "XXX$", ""))
```

I know that *udf*s are known to be slow but is it faster to evaluate a regexp for each row ?

**[2018-01-21 update based on answer by user8983815]**

I've written a benchmarch and the results are a bit surprising

```
[info] Benchmark                                      Mode  Cnt    Score   Error  Units
[info] RemoveSuffixBenchmark.builtin_optimized        avgt   10  103,188 ± 3,526  ms/op
[info] RemoveSuffixBenchmark.builtin_regexp_replace_  avgt   10   99,173 ± 7,313  ms/op
[info] RemoveSuffixBenchmark.udf                      avgt   10   94,570 ± 5,707  ms/op
```

For those who are interested, the code is here : https://github.com/YannMoisan/spark-jmh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt `regexp_replace` will cause serious performance issue, but if you really concerned

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def removeSuffix(c: Column) = when(c.endsWith("XXX"), c.substr(lit(0), length(c) - 3)).otherwise(c)
```

Used as:

```
scala> Seq("fooXXX", "bar").toDF("s").select(removeSuffix($"s").alias("s")).show
+---+
|  s|
+---+
|foo|
|bar|
+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

how about if you cast to DataSet and do:

e.g.

```
case class InputData(col1: String, col2: String)
case class OutputData(col1: String, col2: String)

val suffix = "."

def clean(i: InputData): OutputData = {
  OutputData(
    col1 = i.col1.stripSuffix(suffix).toLowerCase,
    col2 = i.col2,
  )
}

df.as[InputData].map(clean).toDF
```